# ExpressionEngine & Taxonomy 3 - How to split nodes into blocks of 5?

Tags: expressionengine, taxonomy, expressionengine3

I am using ExpressionEngine 2.10.3 and also Taxonomy 3 plugin. I have the following code which, when run, returns the 15 nodes I have set up:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    {exp:taxonomy:nav tree_id="1" display_root="no" root_node_id="2"}
        <li>
            <a href="{node_url}">{node_title}</a>
        </li>
    {/exp:taxonomy:nav}
</div>
```

What I would like to do is after every 5 entries, end the current `<div>` and start a new `col-md-4`. Usually, I would use `{switch}` and I have tried it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    {exp:taxonomy:nav tree_id="1" display_root="no" root_node_id="2"}
        <li>
            <a href="{node_url}">{node_title}</a>
        </li>
        {switch='||||</div><div class="col-md-4">'}
    {/exp:taxonomy:nav}
</div>
```

But it doesn't work at all, instead it just prints out `{switch='||||'}`

Is there any way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on 2.7.1 or greater **and** your taxonomy:nav has the *nav_count* variable, use the [modulo operator](https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/the-modulus-operator).  Instead of your {switch...} thing, put

```
{if nav_count % 5 == 1}
  </div><div class="col-md-4">
{/if}
```

If you end on an modulo-5 count, though, you're going to have an empty div....

Comment: I'll give this a go tomorrow :)

Comment: This is the best way, I tried doing this yesterday as it was the only way I could think of doing it. FYI, `nav_count` for taxonomy should be `node_count` :)